# Project Reactor timeout

Tags: java, project-reactor

I am working on a project reactor workshop and am stuck with the following task:

```
/**
     * TODO 5
     * <p>
     * For each item call received in colors flux call the {@link #simulateRemoteCall} operation.
     * Timeout in case the {@link #simulateRemoteCall} does not return within 400 ms, but retry twice
     * If still no response then provide "default" as a return value
     */
```

The problem I can't wrap my head around is that Flux never actually throws the TimeOutException! I am able to observe this in the console log:

```
16:05:09.759 [main] INFO Part04HandlingErrors - Received red delaying for 300 
16:05:09.781 [main] INFO Part04HandlingErrors - Received black delaying for 500 
16:05:09.782 [main] INFO Part04HandlingErrors - Received tan delaying for 300
```

I tried to play around with the order of the statements, though it didn't seem to change the behaviour. Note: In addition, I tried the overloaded variant of timeout() which accepts a default value that should be returned, if no element is emitted.

```
public Flux<String> timeOutWithRetry(Flux<String> colors) {

        return colors
                .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(400))
                //.timeout(Duration.ofMillis(400), Mono.just("default"))
                .retry(2)
                .flatMap(this::simulateRemoteCall)
                .onErrorReturn(TimeoutException.class, "default");

    }
```

Can someone clear up why the timeout doesn't occur? I suspect that the mechanism is somehow not "bound" to the method invoked by flatMap.

For completeness: The helper method:

```
public Mono<String> simulateRemoteCall(String input) {
        int delay = input.length() * 100;
        return Mono.just(input)
                .doOnNext(s -> log.info("Received {} delaying for {} ", s, delay))
                .map(i -> "processed " + i)
                .delayElement(Duration.of(delay, ChronoUnit.MILLIS));
    }
```

More completeness, this is the test I am given to verify the functionality:

```
@Test
    public void timeOutWithRetry() {
        Flux<String> colors = Flux.just("red", "black", "tan");

        Flux<String> results = workshop.timeOutWithRetry(colors);

        StepVerifier.create(results).expectNext("processed red", "default", "processed tan").verifyComplete();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of Martin Tarjányi is correct, but you also asked why in your code

```
    return colors
            .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(400))
            //.timeout(Duration.ofMillis(400), Mono.just("default"))
            .retry(2)
            .flatMap(this::simulateRemoteCall)
            .onErrorReturn(TimeoutException.class, "default");
```

no timeout occurs.

The reason is that if the elements of the `colors` flux are available, then invoking `.timeout(Duration.ofMillis(400))` has no effect as `timeout` only propagates a `TimeoutException` if *no* item is emitted within the given duration of 400ms, but this is not the case in this example.

As a consequence the element is emitted and `retry(2)` has no effect either. Next you invoke `simulateRemoteCall` on the emitted element which takes some time, but which does not return an error. The result of your code is (beyond timing differences) the same as if you simply apply a map on the given flux:

```
public Flux<String> timeOutWithRetry(Flux<String> colors) {
    return colors.map(s -> "processed " + s);
}
```

If you want to see a timeout on invocation of `simulateRemoteCall` then you must add the `timeout` method after this invocation.

Instead of using `flatMap` you could also use `concatMap`. The difference is whether the order should be preserved or not, i.e. whether the `default` values may occur out of order or not.

Using `concatMap` the answer looks as follows:

```
public Flux<String> timeOutWithRetry(Flux<String> colors) {
    return colors.concatMap(
            color -> simulateRemoteCall(color)
                        .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(400))
                        .retry(2)
                        .onErrorReturn("default"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right in that it's the order and place of the statements that is incorrect.
Since you want to retry/timeout/error-handle the remote call, you should put these operators on the `Mono` of the remote call instead of the `Flux`.

Timeout on `Flux` observes the time elapsed between subsequent elements. However, when you use `flatMap` you get concurrency out of the box and delay between elements practically will be zero (assuming the `colors` `Flux` is sourced by an in-memory list). So this operator should not be put directly on the `Flux` to achieve your goal.

Retry on `Flux` means it resubscribes to the source in case of error, which depending on the source could result in re-processing already processed elements. Instead, you want to retry failed elements only, so it also should be put on `Mono`.

```java
public Flux<String> timeOutWithRetry(Flux<String> colors) {

    return colors.flatMap(color -> simulateRemoteCall(color).timeout(Duration.ofMillis(400))
                                                            .retry(2)
                                                            .onErrorReturn("default"));
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I do see the difference now of adding retry() and timeout() operators to the Flux compared to the Mono resulting from the async function not the Flux. Nevertheless, I still see the same output in the logs. Could it be that the helper method is actually the culprit?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: it should print "processed red", "default", "processed tan". I added the unit test from the workshop in my post. So the timeout should hit for the second string and return "default" instead of "processed black"